# limit dynamic form fields based on data element

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code that allows the adding and removing of selection fields dynamically:

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="multi-field-wrapper">
      <div class="multi-fields">
        <div class="multi-field">

<select class="input-normal selection"name="options1[]" data-limit="2">
<option value="">None</option>
<option value="option1">Option 1</option>
</select>

    <button type="button" class="remove-field">X</button>
    </div></div>


<button type="button" class="add-field">Add</button>
    </div>


<div class="multi-field-wrapper">
      <div class="multi-fields">
        <div class="multi-field">

<select class="input-normal selection"name="options2[]" data-limit="3">
<option value="">None</option>
<option value="option1">Option 1</option>
</select>

    <button type="button" class="remove-field">X</button>
    </div></div>


<button type="button" class="add-field">Add</button>
    </div>
```

Here is the JS:

```
$('.multi-field-wrapper').each(function() {
        var $wrapper = $('.multi-fields', this);
        $(".add-field", $(this)).click(function(e) {
            $('.multi-field:first-child', $wrapper).clone(true).appendTo($wrapper).find('input').val('').focus();
        });
        $('.multi-field .remove-field', $wrapper).click(function() {
            if ($('.multi-field', $wrapper).length > 1)
                $(this).parent('.multi-field').remove();
        });
});
```

What I have been struggling with is the ability to limit the number of selection fields that can be added. I added `data-limit="2"` in attempts to write some JS that references the data value and sets the **limit** based on the value.

Any ideas where to start?

I tried the following which I do not know why it did not work:

```
var article = document.getElementByClass('multi-fields');
var len = $(".multi-field-wrapper").find(".multi-fields").length;
         if(len == article.dataset.limit){
            $('#add-field').hide();
         }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a bit ugly solution, but you can use it as a base. I would put data-limit somewhere outside of the select field, maybe to multi-fields, <strike>so you can create a function to access multi-field.length and data-limit in add and remove clicks</strike>
EDIT: simplified a bit and fixed, when removing selection, it should be less than limit, so we don't need to count select boxes ..
EDIT2: now you can use as many select boxes as you want

```js
$('.multi-field-wrapper').each(function() {
  var $wrapper = $('.multi-fields', this);
  $(".add-field", $(this)).click(function(e) {
    limit = $('.selection', $wrapper).length + 1;
    $select = $('.multi-field:first-child', $wrapper);
    if(limit < $select.find('.selection').data('limit'))
      $(this).show();
    else $(this).hide();
    $select.clone(true).appendTo($wrapper).find('input').val('').focus();
  });
  $('.multi-field .remove-field', $wrapper).click(function() {
    if ($('.multi-field', $wrapper).length > 1) {
      $(this).closest('.multi-field-wrapper').find('.add-field').show();
      $(this).parent('.multi-field').remove();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="multi-field-wrapper">
  <div class="multi-fields">
    <div class="multi-field">
      <select class="input-normal selection" name="options1[]" data-limit="3">
        <option value="">None</option>
        <option value="option1">Option 1x</option>
      </select>

      <button type="button" class="remove-field">X</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <button type="button" class="add-field">Add</button>
</div>

<div class="multi-field-wrapper">
  <div class="multi-fields">
    <div class="multi-field">
      <select class="input-normal selection" name="options2[]" data-limit="5">
        <option value="">None</option>
        <option value="option1">Option 2x</option>
      </select>

      <button type="button" class="remove-field">X</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button type="button" class="add-field">Add</button>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks and I will play around a bit.... how does this change when there are more than one select fields like options1[] and options2[]

Comment: current code works for all selects with `.selection` class, so if you want to have different limits for each select, just filter by name tag, or add specific ID for each of them. but for this behavior you need to play around with add/remove functions as well.

Comment: noob question, where would I need to / how would i filter for name tag

Comment: this should work `$select.find('select[name=options1]').data('limit')`, but I don't know what exactly you're trying to achieve, so can't say if you need to develop multiple functions or one complex that will take care of select variations

Comment: for a simple (prob crappy) solution could I use a switch statement where the if is. I have 7 select variations